# Converting text column to xml column in postgres

Tags: postgresql, geonetwork

My problem is this:

I use a software (geonetwork - http://geonetwork-opensource.org/) that populates a postgres database with plenty of tables. One of those tables is the "data" table that stores plenty of interesting xml files (each row in the table contains the information of a single and complete xml file with all the right syntax).

Unfortunately, geonetwork creates this column using the type "text" instead of "xml", now I want to create a view that converts the xml information that is stored as text in that column to an xml column, so I can go through the information within the xml, that is not really accessible when stored as a text.

But how do I do that?

I found this in the documentation, but no good example of how to actually do the trick.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-xml.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createview.html

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you simply trying casting it to `xml` like: `column::xml`

Comment: No, I don't dare changing the existing data table, as it might interfere with geonetwork doing its job.

Comment: I didn't suggest to change the table, just cast the value when selecting: `select column::xml from the_table`